# Document Library Permissions (READ) being bypassed when using “Open with Windows Explorer”

Tags: permissions, open-with-explorer

I have read lots of Questions and Answers regarding this, however there appears to be no straight answer.

When I log in as a READ only user, if I select a document I cannot delete it, however, I can access the "Open With Explorer" button in the ribbon and then delete the documents. If I press refresh, they are indeed deleted. 
I obviously need the OWE to shuffle files around as an admin, but read only viewers should not have access to the OWE. As well, if the toolbar is enabled in the Library, then once logged in as a Read Only users, the Actions button is active with the OWE as the only option, again, not a good idea as they can open the OWE and delete files. They are confirmed as READ only users.

I could certainly use some help.